# Python - library loading from different project

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

Hello dear Stack community,

I am stuck with exporting my Python project to executable file. I use PyCharm on Windows 10, Python 3.8. I checked for Project Interpreter - it is loading *Python.exe* from right project.
My project works well once I start it from IDE, but when I export it by command :

`pyinstaller --onefile Gui.py -n Foo`

When running *Foo.exe* I get error like on screenshot attached. Issue is that Python looks for library  *openpyxl* from other location, from other project. I checked my project(where *Gui.py* is) for it in *...venv/Lib/site-packages*, it is there. But I cannot make my .exe work. How can I make it load library from right project? Or is it issue with something else?

Help me StackOverflow community, you are my only hope.
[image: Errors when executing]

Answer (score 1):

Export it with the command `pyinstaller --onefile (filename) --hidden-import (the python file you want to import on the main file) -n (name you want)`